# Conversion of Image type to Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some trouble converting the below Image data type to text;

`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`

I have tried casting as `varbinary` and then casting that to `nvarchar`, but get what looks like Unicode characters;

```
select top 1 cast(cast(body as varbinary(max)) as nvarchar(max)) from dbo.messagedata
```

[image]

How can I convert the above Image data into readable text?

Comment: What do you mean by readable text? The point is that the data is binary and not readable by a human. What text would you expect an image to take? I suspect that isn't really what you want. What are you trying to accomplish? BTW, the image datatype has been deprecated in favor of varbinary(max) for over a decade now.

Comment: There is readable text, encoded behind that binary data. I know that for a fact. The database I am dealing is well over a decade old. I know Image type is depreciated, but I didn't make the database.

Comment: Really??? Readable to turn it into an image perhaps but it is not going to just start reading like text. What you are seeing is a text representation of the binary data. The data you posted is exactly what I would expect for the text representation of a binary. Are you trying to display this as an image in some application?

Comment: Managed to sort it myself anyway. Turns out the data is GZip compressed. I decompressed the bytes in C# and managed to get the text back.